# Can I record workout data to GoogleFit from WearOS app?

Tags: wear-os, google-fit

I'm making a fitness wearOS app.
I want to record workouts completed with the app to GoogleFit.

Is there a way to do that from WearOS?

I start a workout using HealthServices:

> ```
> suspend fun startExercise() {
>     val dataTypes = setOf(
>         DataType.HEART_RATE_BPM,
>         DataType.LOCATION
>
>     )
>     val aggregateDataTypes = setOf(
>         DataType.DISTANCE,
>         DataType.TOTAL_CALORIES
>     )
>     val config = ExerciseConfig.builder()
>         .setExerciseType(ExerciseType.RUNNING)
>         .setDataTypes(dataTypes)
>         .setAggregateDataTypes(aggregateDataTypes)
>         .setShouldEnableAutoPauseAndResume(false)
>         .setShouldEnableGps(true)
>         .build()
>     HealthServices.getClient(this /*context*/)
>         .exerciseClient
>         .startExercise(config)
>         .await()
> }
> ```

(Code is from this example https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/health-services/active#start)

I was expecting if I would start/end a workout with `HealthServices` it would auto-magically sync the data to GoogleFit(Apple does this with for HealthKit).

So, can I record workout data to GoogleFit from a WearOS app?

Comment: There is no automatic way, you currently need to read the data, transform it and write to the Fit API.

Comment: @YuriSchimke do you know, by any chance, is the automatic way on Google/WearOS road map? Or any other channel besides StackOverflow where to ask this kind of question? I didn't find here who else can I ask https://developers.google.com/fit/support

Answer (score 2):

To add to the Yuri's comment that this isn't possible automatically, the `SessionClient` is probably what you'd want in order to do this manually. The flow would be:

1. Collect data with Health Services
2. Transform
3. Insert session with `SessionClient`

The [insert a session](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#insert-session) snippet in the Google Fit docs is a relevant example, as it both sets the session type (in this case, running) and then also adds the underlying data (instead of doing that separately with `HistoryClient`).

**Update:** You may also wish to take a look at [Health Connect](https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect), which was recently announced.